# overlapping text in vue component for doughnut chart.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, chart.js

I have a chart.js doughnut chart vue component as below

The problem is that when i use multiple chart instances the text in the middle overlap.

But they are overlapped. I tried changing titles pacing, but that didn't do anything. How can I fix this?
I like to have control over the HTML / whatever which gets outputted to the label.

[image]

```
<script>
import { Doughnut } from "vue-chartjs";

export default {
  name: "doughnutChart",
  extends: Doughnut,
  props: {
    data1: {
      type: String,
      // default: function() {
      //   return;
      // }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    var value = this.data1;
    var data = {
      labels: ["My val", ""]
    };
    this.renderChart({
      datasets: [{
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: ["#FF6384", "#AAAAAA"],
        hoverBackgroundColor: ["#FF6384", "#AAAAAA"],
        hoverBorderColor: ["#FF6384", "#ffffff"],
        data: [value, 100 - value]
      }]
    }, {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: true,
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      cutoutPercentage: 70,
      elements: {
        center: {
          text: '50%' //set as you wish
        }
      },
      tooltips: {
        filter: function(item, data) {
          var label = data.labels[item.index];
          if (label) return item;
        }
      }
    });
    this.textCenter(value)
  },
  methods: {
    textCenter(val) {
      Chart.pluginService.register({
        beforeDraw: function(chart) {
          var width = chart.chart.width,
            height = chart.chart.height,
            ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

          ctx.restore();
          var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
          ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
          ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

          var text = val + "%",
            textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
            textY = height / 2;

          ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
          ctx.save();
        }
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: This is the first result in google when you search for "vue chartjs overlapping text", if anybody still have this problem is most likely because you have to register the plugin locally. Check https://vue-chartjs.org/api/#addplugin

Comment: Registering the `beforeDraw` hook globally is fine but you must make sure it gets registered once only. Please take a look at the following answer that deals with a similar case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64728299/2358409